# Sidebar list option positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

I am working for this small project where there are two sections at the bottom. 
"Configure and Analyze"

[Reference link](http://prntscr.com/bmwqum)

My major concerns is if the data under "Landing" option is less then both below option will show as it is. If the data in landing option is more the option should fixed at the bottom.

Note: When I close the landing option accordian the other two option should go upward.

I need a quick help with the logic implementation.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 editor-sidebar sidebar">
                <div class="editor-accordion">
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Build</a>
                                    </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="panel-body panel-scroll">
                                    <div class="ed-sidebar editor-tab" data-toggle="landing">
                                        <span class="visible-parent"><a href="#" class="section-head"><span class="circle"></span>Landing Page</a>
                                      </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ed-sidebar editor-tab" data-toggle="question">
                                        <span class="add-visible-parent"><a href="#" class="section-head"><span class="circle">&nbsp;</span>Questionner</a>
                                        </span>
                                        <div class="ed-sidebar-sub">
                                            <a href="#" class="sub-head"><span class="hollow"></span>Platform</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><span class="hollow"></span>
                                                    <a href="#" class="ellipsis head">Q. Which paltform will</a>

                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ed-sidebar-sub">
                                            <a href="#" class="sub-head"><span class="hollow"></span>Platform</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><span class="hollow"></span>
                                                    <a href="#" class="ellipsis head">Q. Which paltform will</a>

                                                </li>
                                                <li><span class="hollow"></span>
                                                    <a href="#" class="ellipsis head">Q. Which paltform will</a>

                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ed-sidebar-sub">
                                            <a href="#" class="sub-head"><span class="hollow"></span>Platform</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><span class="hollow"></span>
                                                    <a href="#" class="ellipsis head">Q. Which paltform will</a>

                                                </li>
                                                <li><span class="hollow"></span>
                                                    <a href="#" class="ellipsis head">Q. Which paltform will</a>

                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ed-sidebar editor-tab" data-toggle="result">
                                        <a href="#" class="section-head"> <span class="circle"></span>Result Page </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom-sticky">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Configure</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    dfsadfsaf
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">Analyze</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    sfdsfggasdf
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ed-sidebar-topsection hide">
                    <span>Pages</span>
                    <div class="page-add">
                        <label>Add</label>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucvytb1m/2/)

Comment: please provide a code or jsfiddle so we can understand the problem

Comment: @AllanEmpalmado I added the fiddle link You can have a look.